# Primevue not working in vue module federation

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to do module federation between Nuxt and vue app. Nuxt app will be a host and vue app will be remote. My vue app using Primevue as component library. I am able to load vue components in nuxt except the primevue components. It should looks like below image. Here is the repo https://github.com/ravinsinghd/module-federation-nuxt-vue

[image]

But it's render like this.

[image]

Remote App:

**NavBar.vue**

```js
<template>
  NavBar Component
  <Button label="Submit" />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
```

**Main.ts**

```js
import 'primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css';
import './assets/main.css';

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.vue';
import Button from 'primevue/button';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(PrimeVue);
app.component('Button', Button);
app.component('NavBar', NavBar);
app.mount('#app');
```

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    minify: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: 'remote-app',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './NavBar': './src/components/NavBar.vue',
      },
      shared: ['primevue/config', 'primevue/button'],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Host App:

**nuxt.config.ts**

```js
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['primevue'],
  },
  app: {
    head: {},
  },
  vite: {
    build: {
      target: 'esnext',
      minify: false,
    },
    plugins: [
      federation({
        name: 'host-app',
        remotes: {
          remote_app: 'http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js',
        },
        shared: ['primevue/config', 'primevue/button'],
      }),
    ],
  },
});
```

**default.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    Some default layout shared across all pages
    <slot />
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div>
      <NavBar></NavBar>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import NavBar from 'remote_app/NavBar';
onMounted(() => {});
</script>
```

Comment: Rather than adding vite plugin federation, using primevue as a nuxt plugin may serve your cause.